# What are the domain and codomain of an arrow in Rel, the category of relations?

Tags: functions, category-theory, definition, relations

I will first state my question and then say why it is causing me a problem.

**Question**:
In the definitions of Rel, the category of relations, that I found (nLab, Wikipedia, and Awodey's book), the objects of Rel are said to be sets, and the arrows $A \to B$ are relations from A to B, that is, subsets of $A\times B$. This definition seems problematic to me.

If that is the case, $R \subseteq A\times B$ implies $ R \subseteq (A\cup \{*\}) \times B$, where $ * \notin A$. So, what is true: $dom(R)=A$ or $dom(R)=A\cup \{*\}$? The same question applies to codomains, and with any other set larger than A in its place.

**Why this question**:
The reason why this is causing me a problem is that in the second problem of Awodey's book's first chapter, he asks us to check whether $ Sets \cong Sets^{op} $. I couldn't solve it, and when I checked the solutions in the back, he says that, in Sets, there is only 1 arrow from the empty set $\emptyset$. Now, if things are like I was thinking, then each relation (and so the functions, since they are also relations) of type $A \to B$ is not simply a subset of $A\times B$ but also carries some label to connect it specifically to $A$ and $B$.

The problem is that such a label would allow many functions from the empty set to itself and other sets by changing the label. Each one would be a differently labelled empty set like $\emptyset = \emptyset \times A$. If the empty set doesn't count as a function, then Sets doesn't have an identity arrow for $\emptyset$, so it must count and the problem follows.

I appreciate any answer, but if you could also connect it to the solution to this problem, I would be very happy.

Comment: The $R$ you cite is really two different $R$s depending on what you take the domain to be.  It’s not the same “$R$.”

Comment: The ordered pair domain and codomain are the "labels" you talk about, so there's no question of multiple arrows from $\varnothing$ to itself.

Answer (score 4):

The thing is that a relation between $A$ and $B$ is not *just* a subset of $A\times B$, it is the data of $A$, $B$, and that subset. Exactly the same as for functions: the subset is just the graph of the relation, and though it contains the actually interesting information, technically speaking it is not the whole relation.

So if $R\subset A\times B$, it defines a relation $A\to B$, and also a relation $A\times \{\ast\}\to B$, but it is technically not quite the same relation.